# What is the elegant way to request confirmation for user deletion inside modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic, user-experience

This question is more a logic or best practice question than a technical one.

I have a form creator/render where certain admin users can design a form, and other general users can then use these already created a defined forms to request stuff.

On the general edit section of the form designer, user can move a component up, down, edit or delete it. For the deletion, I am looking for getting confirmation before actual deletion, so the way I could make it works is pretty much like this:

When the user click the delete button, a hidden html is displayed that request confirmation

```
$scope.clickDeleteButton = function ( index ) {
  // log only for reference. Need to be removed
  console.log('Delete button pressed');
  deletion = true;
};
```

because var deletion is true this is confirmation is displayed

```
<div  ng-show="confirmDeletion()" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    Please confirm that you want to delete the component
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" ng-click="deletionConfirmed($parent.$index)">Confirm</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" ng-click="deletionCancelled()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And when the confirmation requested is accepted, then I process the deletion.

```
$scope.deletionConfirmed = function ( index ) {
  //call deletion method in currentForm
  console.log('Delete item with index: ', index);
  FormServ.currentFormData.deleteItem(index);
};
```

This do the trick, but I dont feel it right. How is it done in real projects? Remember, I am already working on a modal so as far as I understand you cannot open a second modal.

Comment: This sounds more like a UX issues than "logic". Why don't you just transition (css animation) an "are you sure?" button in the same form which will activate the final delete?

Comment: Reading you comments make me think you may be right on your point that this maybe more a UX question than logic. I will google how to make that transition. I am in learning phase, so limited knowledge.